# Continuity of basic functions

Tags: calculus

Why is the function $y=b^x$ continuous on the real line (for$\quad b>0,  b\neq 1$).

I understand why $b$ has to be greater than $0$, but not why it cannot be $1$

When I graph on a graphing calculator $1^x$, it seems to be continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f(x) = 1^{x}$ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. In fact, $1^{x} = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and constant functions are continuous. Certainly, the value $b = 1$ fits the condition $b > 0$. So I'm not sure why this is an issue.

Comment: I got this out of a textbook

Answer (score 0):

$y = 1^x$ is continuous. As you point out it is constant. Often the base $b=1$ is not included in the definition of exponential functions because it has no inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Analytically,

$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = 1 = f(c).$$

Therefore, $f$ is continuous everywhere.